# ¿Como Imprimir reportes PDF por rango de Fecha en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, php7, php8

Espero me puedan ayudar, estoy intentando generar reportes PDF por fecha. Pero no he podido solucionar, lo que quiero que me muestre el PDF con el formato y diseño que ya establecí y solo me muestre los registros que fueron registrados en la fecha que yo seleccione en mi formulario, me imprime los reportes en PDF por ID es decir por cada registro puedes imprimir cada reporte, lo que quiero es que por medio de filtrado de fecha me genere todos los reportes especificamente por la fecha seleccionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el código de mi formulario y de mi PDF, en verdad espero me puedan ayudar para poder solucionar este problema que tengo días, y no encuentro algo parecido.

```js
<?php
/* Una construcción del lenguaje no requiere paréntesis, no tiene parámetros */
include('PDF_MC_Table.php');
require_once '../controlador/conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

/* Antes de hacer uso de variables POST comprobamos su existencia */
if (
    empty($_POST['fechainc']) === false
    && empty($_POST['fechafin']) === false
) {
    /* Escapamos las fechas para evitar inyección SQL */
    $fecha1 = $conexion->prepare($_POST['fechainc']);
    $fecha2 = $conexion->prepare($_POST['fechafin']);


    /* Enviamos las cabeceras para la descarga del archivo */
    //header('Content-Type: text/pdf; charset=utf-8');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte_Registros(CMAPS).pdf"');

   // $id_row = $_GET['id'];

    $pdf = new FPDF($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'mm');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
    $textypos = 5;
    $pdf->setY(12);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    
    //Consulta a la base de datos
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT *, CASE 
    WHEN cuadrilla =1 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad'
    WHEN cuadrilla =2 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Operación Mega sistema'
    WHEN cuadrilla =3 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Drenajes'
    WHEN cuadrilla =4 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas'
    WHEN cuadrilla =5 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Cloración'
    WHEN cuadrilla =6 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Bacheo'
    WHEN cuadrilla =7 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Contratos'
    WHEN cuadrilla =8 THEN 'otros'
    ELSE 'Cuadrilla desconocida'
    END cuadrillas FROM sanandre_cmaps.reportes BETWEEN '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2'
    ORDER BY fecha_inicio DESC");
    $data = $resultado->fetchAll();
    //$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM reportes BETWEEN CAST '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2'
    //ORDER BY fecha_inicio DESC");
    
    
    // Agregamos los datos de la empresa
    //$pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, "ORDEN DE TRABAJO CMAPS");
    $pdf->Image('logo.jpg', 35, 10, 133);
    $pdf->setY(30);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(185, 20, utf8_decode('ORDEN DE TRABAJO CMAPS'), 0, 0, 'C');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/mexico_city');
    
    // Agregamos los datos de la orden
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->setY(30);
    $pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
    $pdf->setY(35);
    $pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
    $pdf->Cell(54, 45, "Hora Generada: " . date('H:i:s'), 0, 1, 'R');
    $pdf->setY(40);
    $pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 45, "Fecha Generada: " . date("d/m/y"), 0, 1, "R");
    $pdf->setY(75);
    $pdf->setX(80);
    $pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, "DATOS DE LA PERSONA QUE REPORTA");
    $pdf->setY(120);
    $pdf->setX(80);
    $pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, "CUADRILLA RESPONSABLE");
    $pdf->setY(160);
    $pdf->setX(80);
    $pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, utf8_decode("FINALIZACIÓN DEL TRABAJO"));
    
    //Mueve la posición del Array Folio
    $pdf->setY(55);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    //// Array de Cabecera Folio
    $header = array (utf8_decode("N.DE ORDEN:"));
    
    // Column widths
    $w = array(20);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 2, 0,);
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $pdf->SetXY(30, 55);
        $pdf->Cell($w[0], 7, utf8_decode($row['folio']), 0,);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    //Mueve la posición del Array alta reporte
    $pdf->setY(60);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    //// Array de Cabecera Folio
    $header = array (utf8_decode("FECHA Y HORA DEL REPORTE:"));
    
    // Column widths
    $w = array(20);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 2, 0,);
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $pdf->SetXY(55, 60);
        $pdf->Cell($w[0], 7, utf8_decode($row['fecha_inicio']), 0,);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    
    $pdf->setY(153);
    $pdf->setX(138);
    //// Array de Cabecera Fecha y hora Finalizado
    $header = array (utf8_decode("FECHA Y HORA DE FINALIZACIÓN"));
    
    // Column widths
    $w = array(64);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0,'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $pdf->SetXY(138, 160);
        $pdf->Cell($w[0], 7, utf8_decode($row['otros']), 1,);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    /// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de Orden
    $pdf->setY(80);
    $pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Ln();
    
    //// Array de Cabecera
    $header = array("NOMBRE(S)", "APELLIDOS", utf8_decode("DIRECCIÓN"), utf8_decode("TELÉFONO"), "CONTRATO");
    
    // Column widths
    $w = array(30, 40, 80, 20, 22,);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 5, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $pdf->Cell($w[0], 12, utf8_decode($row["nombre"]), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[1], 12, utf8_decode($row["apellido"]), 1);
        $pdf->MultiCell($w[2], 5, utf8_decode($row["direccion"]), 1);
        //cambia la posicion de los cuadros telefono y medidor
        $pdf->SetXY(160, 92);
        $pdf->Cell($w[3], 12, utf8_decode($row["telefono"]), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[4], 12, utf8_decode($row["num_contrato"]), 1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    // Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de Cuadrilla
    $pdf->setY(115);
    $pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Ln();
    
    //// Array de Cabecera
    $header = array("TURNADO A", utf8_decode("SUBDIRECCIÓN"), "RESPONSABLE", "NOMBRE(S)", "FECHA");
    
    // Column widths
    $w = array(45, 40, 40, 40, 27);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 5, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        //$pdf->Cell($w[0], 6, $row[utf8_decode('cuadrillas')], 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[0], 12, utf8_decode($row["cuadrillas"]), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[1], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[2], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[3], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[4], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    // Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de tipo de orden
    $pdf->setY(155);
    $pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Ln();
    
    //// Array de Cabecera
    $header = array("PROBLEMA REPORTADO", utf8_decode("OBSERVACIÓN"), utf8_decode("CENTRO DE ATENCIÓN USUARIOS"));
    
    // Column widths
    $w = array(64, 64, 64);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $pdf->MultiCell($w[0], 5, utf8_decode($row["observaciones"]), 1);
        $pdf->SetXY(74, 174);
        $pdf->Cell($w[1], 20, utf8_decode($row['otra_descripcion']), 1);
        $pdf->Cell($w[2], 20, utf8_decode($row['otros']), 1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    
    // Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de Martial y Herramientas
    $pdf->setY(190);
    $pdf->setX(195);
    $pdf->Ln();
    /////////////////////////////
    //// Array de Cabecera
    $header = array("MATERIAL Y HERRAMIENTAS UTILIZADAS");
    //// Arrar de Productos
    $products = array(
        array(""),
    );
    // Column widths
    $w = array(193);
    // Header
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
        $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    // Data
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($products as $row) {
        $pdf->Cell($w[0], 35, $row[0], 1);
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
    
    //Firma del uuario.
    $pdf->setY(253);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(120, 20, utf8_decode('____________________________'), 0, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->setY(256);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(120, 20, utf8_decode('FIMA DEL USUARIO'), 0, 0, 'C');
    
    //Firma del Reponsable
    $pdf->setY(253);
    $pdf->setX(20);
    $pdf->Cell(230, 20, utf8_decode('____________________________'), 0, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->setY(256);
    $pdf->setX(20);
    $pdf->Cell(230, 20, utf8_decode('FIRMA CUADRILLA'), 0, 0, 'C');
    
    $pdf->output();

}
```

Este apartado es mi formulario para seleccionar las fechas y generar mi PDF

```js
<form action="../Reports/prueba.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 sclass">
    <input type="date" name="fechainc" placeholder="Fecha inicio" required class="form-control mr-sm-2"><br />
    <input type="date" name="fechafin" placeholder="Fecha final" required class="form-control mr-sm-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Generar</button>
</form>
```

Este es el error que me manda cuando le doy generar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi conexion a base de datos

```js
<?php 
class Conexion{   
    public static function Conectar() {        
        define('servidor', 'localhost');
        define('nombre_bd', 'sanandre_cmaps');
        define('usuario', 'root');
        define('password', '');                             
        $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');            
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".servidor."; dbname=".nombre_bd, usuario, password, $opciones);            
            return $conexion;
        }catch (Exception $e){
            die("El error de Conexión es: ". $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya por aqui veo un error, porque le preguntas al sistema empty() === false, ya la funcion de por si ya devuelve true o false dependiendo de la acción, alli estas teniendo un error, no se en donde termina ese if, pero lo que si se es que te esta devolviendo falso y por lo tanto no entra en la condicional y por eso no esta ejecutando la consulta por fecha, ademas de que debes validar como te esta devolviendo la fecha ese input y como lo tienes en la bd, no es lo mismo 04/07/20222 a 07/04/2022 o 2022/07/04

Comment: Corrijo: en el sistema haces empty($_POST['fechain']) y te devuelve falso, para que luego le preguntas si es EXACTAMENTE a falso, pero ya esa comprobación estaria de más, seria bueno que colocaras cual es el error que te esta dando

Comment: @ernestojimenez dejé una captura del error que me envía, disculpa, pero soy aún nuevo en la programación.

Comment: Por favor coloca el codigo de la conexion a la bd

Comment: @ernestojimenez ya subí la conexión a mi base de datos.

Comment: Listo, subí mi base de datos @ernestojimenez